# Date format comparison not working

Tags: java, date

Below is my code

```
Date currentDate = new Date();
DateFormat dateFormatCmp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

if(dateFormatCmp.format(currentDate).equals(dateFormatCmp.format(task.getExecutionDate())))
{
  //doSomething here
}
```

current date is having value - 2014-12-02 and 
task.getExecutionDate() is having value  2014-12-05

Even then it is entering into if condition. Date comparison is not done properly.

Comment: Are you really sure? I think you should debug or at least log the result of `dateFormatCmp.format(task.getExecutionDate())`.

Comment: Yes, the values that I have mentioned in the question are after debugging..

Comment: Again: Are you **really** sure? String comparison is not broken. If this is done in multiple threads, then you would be better by logging the value of `dateFormatCmp.format(task.getExecutionDate())`, the name of the thread and some other info that helps you identify the `task` that gives you this issue.

Comment: Try to execute this code http://pastebin.com/J5yYcRL5 to see what values you are actually processing.

Comment: In your real code do you happen to have a ';' behind the if that is not showing here?